# Smoothness Criterion for Vector Fields

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I'm going to just write the proof (straight from Lee), my question is about the $(*)$ starred part.

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and let $X:M \to TM$ be a (rough) vector field.  If $(U,(x^i))$ is any smooth coordinate chart on $M$, then the restriction of $X$ to $U$ is smooth if and only if its competent functions with respect to this chart are smooth.

Remark: Spivak says this smoothness criterion is "by definition" iff each component is smooth.  Lee is extremely pedantic.

None the less.... 
Proof:

Let $(x^i,v^i)$ be the natural coordinates on $\pi^{-1}(U) \subset TM$ associated with the chart $(U,(x^i))$. By the definition of natural coordinates, the coordinate representation of $X:M \to TM$ on $U$ is 
$\hat{U}(x)=(x^1,\cdots,x^n, X^1(x), \cdots,X^n(x))$  $(*)$

where $X^i$ is the $i$th component function of $X$ in $x^i$ coordinates. It follows immediately that smoothness of $X$ in $U$ is equivalent to smoothness of its component functions.

I'm essentially confused about the representation of $X$ on $U$.  Do the first $n$ parts tell us where the vector is "attached" and the last $n$ parts tells us the direction... are the first $n$ parts equivalent to $p$ in the following:
$X_p= X^i(p) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}|_p$

In other words, is this practically where all the information is?

Comment: You're being a little mean with Lee, his book and his style are exceptional throughout, I wouldn't call any of it pedantic.

Comment: No... I agree that Lee has several excellent texts... that's why I'm reading this book. Just being a tad bit cheeky.  Regardless, I'm only concerned about (*).  I am saying Lee is pedantic in the sense that he first defines the more general "rough vector field", something that we didn't even cover in class and more or less took "smooth vector field" as our definition of a vector field.

Comment: I think it's a clever way to replace the phrase "Let $X : M \to TM$ be a map such that $(\pi \circ X) = Id_M$" which is we want to say that we have map $X$ which is not quite a vector field (section), since usually when we say that $X$ is a vector field, it is assumed to be continous or even smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A smooth vector field $ X $, as you know, is a smooth map from two manifolds: $ M $ and $ TM $ such that $ X _p \in T_p(M) $. When you have to verify if a map is smooth you have to represent it in smooth coordinate and verifying that this (local) representation is smooth (with respect to standard notion of smoothness in $ R^n $). 'Lee' criterion is therefore a restatement of the definiton of smooth function. Therefore the answer to your question is yes.